# How to return back to View that contain renderpartial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am creating simple blog,In my article I have 'comment' Partial function. I can pass data to controller and save data successfully, but an error occurs when return back to Article View that contains 'Comment'.

Here is my **Article.cshtml** Page:

```
@model SimpleBlog.Post
 <p class="lead" style="text-align:justify; word-wrap:break-word">
        @Html.Raw(Model.Body)
    </p>

    <hr />

    <div class="well">
        <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
        @Html.Partial("PostComment", new SimpleBlog.Comment(), new ViewDataDictionary {{"PostId",Model.ID} })
    </div>
    <hr />
```

**PostComment.cshtml**

```
@model SimpleBlog.Comment

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostComment", "Home", new { PostId = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["PostId"]) }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, 3, 10, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

Controller for Comment:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostComment(Comment comment, int PostId)
        {
            if (comment != null)
            {
                comment.PostID = PostId;
                string sdate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                comment.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(sdate);
                db.Comments.Add(comment);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ReadMore");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Here is the error:
**The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ReadMore(Int32)' in 'SimpleBlog.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters**

Please Help me, Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that you are redirecting to (ReadMore) is expecting you to pass an id of type (int).

Try the following:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostComment(Comment comment, int PostId)
        {
            if (comment != null)
            {
                comment.PostID = PostId;
                string sdate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                comment.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(sdate);
                db.Comments.Add(comment);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ReadMore",new { Id = PostId});
            }
            return View();
        }
```